# Express js session issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, routes

I have an Express app wherein sessions are troublesome.

The code generally works, following successful login, the user should be directed to a 'dashboard' page (if no specific url has been requested).

login.js sets req.session.user to an object of user info.

To check if any route is authorised, I have a middleware (authuser.js) that checks req.session.user

The problem is that this test is (apparently randomly) failing. Here is an (edited) log of the console, where you can see login.js reporting req.session.user, followed by authuser.js failing the test on req.session.user:

```
Login success - session: Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-08-24T13:30:16.023Z,
     originalMaxAge: 604800000,
     httpOnly: true },
  requested_url: '/dashboard',
  __lastAccess: 1566048616023,
  user: 
   { username: 'me',
     display_name: 'Jeff',
     role: 'admin',
     groups: null,
     set_password: true,
     organisation: 'jeff',
     organisation_id: '1',
     maxDiskSpace: '2048000000',
     default_module: 'default',} }
Login -redirecting to /dashboard
Auth user: No req.session.user /dashboard
POST /login 302 131.560 ms - 64
GET /dashboard 302 1.167 ms - 56
GET /login 200 20.086 ms - 1203
```

app.js:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

var fileStoreOptions = {};
var sess = {
  store: new FileStore(fileStoreOptions),
  secret: 'Fuzz-whib-49',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // 7 days
  }
}

app.use(session(sess));
```

login.js:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  auth.login( req )
  .then( user => {
    req.session.user = user;

    var next_route = req.query.next || req.session.requested_url || '/dashboard';
    delete req.session.requested_url;

    res.redirect(next_route)
  })
  .catch( function( error) {
  ...
```

dashboard.js:

```
router.get('/', authUser, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Dashboard: Session id: ' + req.session.id);
    console.log('Dashboard - user: ' + req.session.user.username); 
    var mod = loadAppModule(req.session.user);
    var title = mod.title;
    res.render("dashboard", { 
      module: mod,
      user: req.session.user,
    });
});
```

authuser.js middleware:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    console.log('Auth user: No req.session.user ' + req.originalUrl)
    req.session.requested_url = req.originalUrl;
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

logout.js

```
router.post('/', authUser, function(req, res, next) {
console.log('Logout ' + req.session.user.username);
    req.session.destroy(function(){
      res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

What gives?

Comment: And if you `console.log(req.session)` in the first line of your middleware, does it exist? did you `app.use(cookieSession...`? Totally off topic but it's better practice to exit early so instead of `if (req.session.user)` handle the negative `(!req.session.user)` and error out so that anything after the if statement is a success and you can just call `next()`.

Comment: What's your `auth.login( req )`, I suspect it's some db call, the failure your described would arise if user is `null`

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with session-file-store. Can it be that my call `"req.session.user = user;"` in login.js has not yet synced to disc when I try to read `req.session.user` in authuser.js?

By using cookie-session instead of session-file-store, the problem goes away ...

app.js:

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
  ...
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: name,
  keys: [key],

  // Cookie Options
  maxAge: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // 7 days
}));
```